# How to handle an empty datagridview?

Tags: c#, datagridview

I am using the datagridview from the toolbox and I want it to look good.
Everything works perfectly but I need some styling advice here.
Because I have a default sized form and when I have many view rows in my datagridview it looks bad because half of the view is the forms background and not my data grid view. But I want it to seem like the whole thing is the table.

Comment: Could you post some code/images? It will help...

Comment: Like that? http://prntscr.com/aqur0k

Comment: @joohaha Set the forms border to "none" and dock the datagridview to the form = Borderless table. But also take in mind that at this state you cant move your table over the screen.

Answer (score 1):

DataGridView rows, columns, and headers can change size as a result of many different occurrences:

**User resize** - Users can make size adjustments by dragging or double-clicking row, column, or header dividers.

**Control resize** - In column fill mode, column widths change when the control width changes; for example, when the control is docked to its parent form and the user resizes the form.

**Cell value change** - In content-based automatic sizing modes, sizes change to fit new display values.

**Method call** - Programmatic content-based resizing lets you make opportunistic size adjustments based on cell values at the time of the method call.
Property setting - You can also set specific height and width values.

By default, user resizing is enabled, automatic sizing is disabled, and cell values that are wider than their columns are clipped.

For more information look [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/74b2wakt(v=vs.100).aspx)

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you want the datagrid view to adjust automatically to the size of the form. In this case, Set the anchor property of the control to hook to all sides of the parent - top, bottom, left, and right.

Answer (score 0):

If you want your form looks like a table you can use Dock property for datagridview. and dock this tool to the form
and then you must do some changes on datagridview view like this:

```
 dataGridView1.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
        dataGridView1.AutoSizeColumnsMode =     DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.Fill;
        dataGridView1.RowHeadersVisible = false;
```

adding some rows and columns for see the setting result

```
 dataGridView1.Columns.Add("column1", "column1");
        dataGridView1.Columns.Add("column2", "column2");
        dataGridView1.Columns.Add("column3", "column3");
        dataGridView1.Columns.Add("column4", "column4");
        dataGridView1.Rows.Add(10);
```

and then you can set form back color and datagridview back color as same color.